# adquirir: Is there another stem-changing verb group? i -> ie

Tags: verbos, conjugación

There is a list of stem-changing verbs present in Spanish grammar books:

```
e -> ie: cerrar, comenzar, empezar, negar, quebrar
o -> ue: acordarse, acostarse, contar, constar, mostrar
u -> ue: jugar
e -> i:  corregir, despedir, elegir, medir
```

Conjugation examples can be found online e.g.: http://www.elearnspanishlanguage.com/grammar/verb/stemchanging.html

```
e -> ie: cerrar

c[ie]rro    cerramos
c[ie]rras   cerráis
c[ie]rra    c[ie]rran
```

I found another stem-changing conjugation, which is not present in grammar books as a category:

```
i -> ie: adquirir

adqu[ie]ro   adquiremos
adqu[ie]res  adquiréis
adqu[ie]re   adqu[ie]ren
```

Why it is not referred in grammar books as a stem-changing category?
Is this an exception?

Comment: there is a list of stem changing verbs in el Presente described in all grammar books. I found i -> ie stem changing verb and wonder why it is not present in grammar books.

Comment: It looks better now. However, I wonder if these all are really in the books. Some of them involve no changing at all: the letters change as a form of avoiding the sounds changing. Example "vencer" with /z/ sound before 'e' uses 'c', but to keep stem sound before 'o' ("venzo") needs letter 'z'. This is not really stem changing, just different letters for the same sound.

Comment: yes, these are letter changing verbs. I think I've found one source with i->ie change: http://www.spanishdict.com/topics/show/38

Comment: it is similar to jugar, but just 2 verbs exists: adquirir, inquirir. grammar books report jugar case but avoid i->ie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three main groups of stem-changing verbs, as you note, they are **o→ue**, **e→ie**, and **e→i**, which are technically o→ue→**u**, e→ie→**i**, and e→i→**i** for *-ir* verbs.

These came from an evolution of the pronunciation of certain Latin vowel sounds when changing from being stressed and unstressed, and the effect is called *alternancia vocálica*.  Verbs aren't the only thing that do it, incidentally, as evidenced in numbers (s**ie**te/n**ue**ve but s**e**tenta/n**o**venta), superlatives (f**ue**rte but f**o**rtísimo), and a handful of other words (h**ué**rfano but **o**rfonato).

There are three special verbs (or a few more by changing prefixes) that don't quite follow the standard changes.

They are *jugar*, *cernir*, and *adquirir*.  *Jugar* is unique because the *-o-* in its infinitive became a *-u-* over time (compare to Galician *xogar*).

*cernir* is unique because, though ending in *-ir*, the second stem-change does not take place: *cierno* but *cernió* (expected but wrong: *cirnió*), *cierna* but *cernamos* (expected but wrong: *cirnamos*).  It could be formally described as a **e→ie→e** verb along with *concernir* and *discernir*.

*Adquirir*, likewise, is just an exception without much rhyme or reason to it.  If I had to take an off-the-cuff guess, it's due to influence from *querer*.  It's also the only one I can think of that does an **i→ie→i** change (along with *inquirir* that has the same root).

Comment: "*Adqu**i**rir* was at an earlier stage *adqu**e**rir*, with a completely regular conjugation following the model of *sentir*. When it subsequently evolved to *adquirir*, the conjugations with diphthongs were left unchanged." [Spanish Verbs Made Simple(r)](https://books.google.es/books?id=iSQPw_NIo30C&pg=PA278#v=onepage&q=adquirir)