# Is "jugar" the only 'u'-to-'ue' stem-changing verb?

Tags: verbos, conjugación

I've heard that "jugar" is the only 'u'-to-'ue' stem-changing verb. Is this true?

Comment: Related: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/6984

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes.**

All stem changing verbs fall into one of three categories (**e→ie<sup>(→i)</sup>**, **e→i<sup>(→i)</sup>**, **o→ue<sup>(→u)</sup>**, where *-ir* verbs do the second change).  There are exactly nine exceptions in three special categories:

- **i→ie→i**
  *adquirir*, *perquirir*, *inquirir*, *preadquirir*
- **e→ie→e**
  *cernir*, *concernir*, *decernir*, *discernir*
- **u→ue**
  *jugar*

The reason for *jugar* being a special case is that it was originally *jogar* (and thus **o→ue**) but for some reason as the vowel shifted the stem change remained.

Comment: Nunca había oído [_decernir_](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Bw2nfSG), que veo que es lo mismo (pero en desuso) que _discernir_.

Comment: @fedorqui yo tampoco hasta hace poco :-)

Comment: El verbo "soldar" aplica tambien?

Comment: @gustavovelascoh *soldar* es un verbo típico de alternancia **o→ue**, no hay nada excepcional en su conjugación.

Comment: This would make a good canonical answer -- you gave a complete run-down.  I'll ask a general question -- would you mind repeating this answer there?  If there's anything to add to make it complete, please do.