# What are the regular and irregular stem-changing verbs?

Tags: verbos

What are the regular and irregular stem-changing verbs?  Please provide both the Spanish and the English terminology.

This is intended as a canonical q-a.

Comment: @ukemi - Please see updated question.

Answer (score 1):

- **cambio de raíz u : ue**

  1. J
     Jugar
- **cambio de raíz o : ue**

  1. A
     absolver
     acordar
     acordarse
     acostar
     acostarse
     agorar
     almorzar
     amoblar
     apostar
     aprobar
     avergonzar
     avergonzarse
  2. C
     cocer
     colar
     colarse
     colgar
     comprobar
     concordar
     conmover
     consolar
     contar
     costar
  3. D
     demostrar
     descomponer
     descontar
     desolar
     desollar
     desosar
     devolver
     disolver
     doler
     dormir
     dormirse
  4. E
     encontrar
     encontrarse
     envolver
     esforzar
     esforzarse
  5. F
     follar
     forzar
  6. L
     llover
  7. M
     moler
     morder
     morir
     morirse
     mostrar
     mostrarse
     mover
     moverse
  8. O
     oler
  9. P
     poder
     probar
     promover
  10. R
      recordar
      remover
      resolver
      revolver
      rodar
      rogar
  11. S
      soldar
      soler
      soltar
      sonar
      soñar
  12. T
      torcer
      tostar
      tostarse
      tronar
  13. V
      volar
      volcar
      volver
      volverse
- c**ambio de raíz e : ie**

  1. A
     abstenerse
     acertar
     adherir
     advertir
     alentar
     apacentar
     apretar
     arrepentirse
     ascender
     asentir
     atender
     atenerse
     atravesar
     avenirse
  2. C
     calentar
     calentarse
     cegar
     cerrar
     comenzar
     concertar
     conferir
     confesar
     consentir
     contener
     contravenir
     convenir
     convertir
     convertirse
  3. D
     defender
     denegar
     descender
     despertar
     despertarse
     detener
     detenerse
     devenir
     diferir
     digerir
     discernir
     disentir
     distender
     divertir
     divertirse
  4. E
     empezar
     encender
     encerrar
     enmendar
     entender
     enterrar
     entretener
     entretenerse
     extender
  5. F
     fregar
  6. G
     gobernar
  7. H
     heder
     helar
     herir
     herrar
     hervir
  8. I
     inferir
     interferir
     intervenir
     invertir
  9. M
     malquerer
     manifestar
     mantener
     mantenerse
     mentar
     mentir
     merendar
  10. N
      negar
      negarse
      nevar
  11. O
      obtener
  12. P
      pensar
      perder
      plegar
      preferir
      presentir
      prevenir
      provenir
  13. Q
      quebrar
      quebrarse
      querer
  14. R
      recomendar
      referir
      referirse
      regar
      requerir
      retener
      reventar
  15. S
      sembrar
      sentar
      sentarse
      sentir
      sentirse
      serrar
      sosegar
      sostener
      sugerir
  16. T
      temblar
      tender
      tener
      tentar
      transferir
      tropezar
  17. V
      venir
      verter
- **cambio de raíz e : i**

  1. A
     adherir
     arrepentirse
     asentir
     avenirse
  2. B
     bendecir
  3. C
     ceñir
     colegir
     competir
     concebir
     conferir
     conseguir
     consentir
     constreñir
     contradecir
     contravenir
     convenir
     convertir
     convertirse
     corregir
  4. D
     decir
     derretir
     derretirse
     despedir
     despedirse
     desteñir
     desvestir
     desvestirse
     devenir
     diferir
     digerir
     disentir
     divertir
     divertirse
  5. E
     elegir
     embestir
     erguir
     estreñir
     expedir
  6. F
     freír
  7. G
     gemir
  8. H
     henchir
     herir
     hervir
  9. I
     impedir
     inferir
     interferir
     intervenir
     invertir
  10. M
      maldecir
      malquerer
      mentir
      morirse
  11. P
      pedir
      perseguir
      predecir
      preferir
      presentir
      prevenir
      proseguir
      provenir
  12. R
      referir
      referirse
      regir
      reír
      reírse
      rendir
      reñir
      repetir
      requerir
  13. S
      seguir
      sentir
      sentirse
      servir
      sofreír
      sonreír
      sugerir
  14. T
      teñir
      transferir
  15. V
      venir
      vestir
      vestirse
- **cambio de raíz i : ie**

  1. A
     adquirir
  2. I
     inquirir

Fuentes :

https://www.esfacil.eu/es/verbos/categorias/17-cambio-de-raiz-u-ue.html
https://www.esfacil.eu/es/verbos/categorias/15-cambio-de-raiz-o-ue.html
https://www.esfacil.eu/es/verbos/categorias/14-cambio-de-raiz-e-ie.html
https://www.esfacil.eu/es/verbos/categorias/16-cambio-de-raiz-e-i.html
https://www.esfacil.eu/es/verbos/categorias/18-cambio-de-raiz-i-ie.html

Comment: is this what you asked for ?

Comment: I guess I can't argue with that -- it seems tremendously comprehensive.  What I was hoping for was the succinct answer given in a recent question, https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/30351/9385